# flask_jwt_extended exceptions NoAuthorizationError

Tags: flask, flask-restful, flask-jwt-extended

I am building the flask app using the flask restful. For generating the access token am using the flask_jwt_extended module. Am able to generate the access_token ,refresh_token, But while accessing the API it is throwing the below error, am passing the access_token in the request headers.

```py
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Apr/2020 13:44:35] "POST /api/protected HTTP/1.1" 405 -
[2020-04-23 13:44:44,742] ERROR in app: Exception on /api/protected [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hasher/test_jwt/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/hasher/test_jwt/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/hasher/test_jwt/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 468, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hasher/test_jwt/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/views.py", line 89, in view
    return self.dispatch_request(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hasher/test_jwt/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 583, in dispatch_request
    resp = meth(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/hasher/test_jwt/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_jwt_extended/view_decorators.py", line 107, in wrapper
    verify_jwt_in_request()
  File "/home/hasher/test_jwt/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_jwt_extended/view_decorators.py", line 32, in verify_jwt_in_request
    jwt_data, jwt_header = _decode_jwt_from_request(request_type='access')
  File "/home/hasher/test_jwt/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_jwt_extended/view_decorators.py", line 314, in _decode_jwt_from_request
    raise NoAuthorizationError(errors[0])
flask_jwt_extended.exceptions.NoAuthorizationError: Missing Authorization Header
127.0.0.1 - - [23/Apr/2020 13:44:44] "GET /api/protected HTTP/1.1" 50
```

- Below is the application code.

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_restful import Resource

from flask_jwt_extended import (
    JWTManager,
    jwt_required,
    create_access_token,
    jwt_refresh_token_required,
    create_refresh_token,
    get_jwt_identity,
)

app = Flask(__name__)


app.config["JWT_SECRET_KEY"] = "super-secret"  # Change this!
jwt = JWTManager(app)

api = Api(app)
class Login(Resource):
    def post(self):
        import pdb

        pdb.set_trace()
        username = request.json.get("username", "test")
        password = request.json.get("password", "test")
        ret = {
            "access_token": create_access_token(identity=username),
            "refresh_token": create_refresh_token(identity=username),
        }

        return ret

class Refresh(Resource):
    @jwt_refresh_token_required
    def post(self):
        current_user = get_jwt_identity()
        ret = {"access_token": create_access_token(identity=current_user)}
        return ret


class Protected(Resource):
    @jwt_required
    def get(self):
        username = get_jwt_identity()
        return dict(logged_in_as=username)


api.add_resource(Login, "/api/login")
api.add_resource(Refresh, "/api/refresh")
api.add_resource(Protected, "/api/protected")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution for this above issue.

While making the request we have to send the headers in the below format. Then it is working fine as expected. We have to add `Bearer` as a prefix to the token, then only it will work. Hope it will help the people who are facing this issue.

```py
refresh_token = (
    "Bearer "
    + "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.                                                                                              
eyJpYXQiOjE1ODc2MzY4MTUsIm5iZiI6MTU4NzYzNjgxNSwianRpIjoiZjRmYjIwN2EtNjk3My00ZDdlLWI0ZDMtMGY4M2RiOGMzZTgxIiwiZXhwIjoxNTkwMjI4ODE1LCJpZGVudG
l0eSI6ImNoYXRyYSIsInR5cGUiOiJyZWZyZXNoIn0.iH7kdCJ5UgeZEO7HgV0QgJbuuSu8ZBDQ3MIrKH5TrDA"
)
headers = dict(Authorization=access_token)
```